# Setting InnerHtml property using HtmlAgilityPack produces unexpected results

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and C# in order to convert older IE  tags as well as Javascript to be compatible with other browsers. Here is an example:

Old code:

```
<script for="thisForm" event="onsubmit()" language="JScript">

var Checked = false
var Counter = 0

for (;Counter < this.choice.length; Counter++)
{
    if (this.choice[Counter].checked)
    {
        Checked = true
        this.action = this.choice[Counter].value
    }
}

if (!Checked)
{
    alert ("Please make a selection")
    return false
}
</script>
```

I convert to:

```
<script ftype="text\JScript">
function thisForm_onsubmit(el)
{
var Checked = false
var Counter = 0

for (;Counter < el.choice.length; counter++)
{
    if (el.choice[counter].checked)
    {
        checked = true
        el.action = el.choice[counter].value
    }
}

if (!checked)
{
    alert ("please make a selection")
    return false
}
}
</script>
```

What I did above is removed for, event, and language attributes from script tag, added type="text/JScript" attribute and wrapped the javascript into a function code.

I do it by simply additing HtmlNode attributes and then replacing InnerHtml property value. So far it worked fine for me untill I encountered the above function. somehow instead of giving me the result above, I get the following:

```
<script type="text/JScript">
function thisForm_onsubmit(el)
{
var Checked = false
var Counter = 0

for (;Counter < el.choice.length; counter++)
{
    if (el.choice[counter].checked)
    {
        checked = true
        el.action = el.choice[counter].value
    }
}

if (!checked)
{
    alert ("please make a selection")
    return false
}

}
  el.choice.length;="" counter++)="" {="" if="" (el.choice[counter].checked)="" {="" checked="true" el.action="el.choice[Counter].value" }="" }="" if="" (!checked)="" {="" alert="" ("please="" make="" a="" selection")="" return="" false="" }="" }=""></ el.choice.length; counter++)
{
    if (el.choice[counter].checked)
    {
        checked = true
        el.action = el.choice[counter].value
    }
}

if (!checked)
{
    alert ("please make a selection")
    return false
}

}
></script>
```

The strange part that the text I am assigning to the InnerHtml is correct, but scriptNode.InnerHtml shows different value

Here is my C# code:

```
 if (scriptNode.Attributes["for"] != null)
 {
                                {
    if (scriptNode.Attributes["for"] != null)
                                        ctrl = scriptNode.Attributes["for"].Value;

                                    if (scriptNode.Attributes["event"] != null)
                                        evt = scriptNode.Attributes["event"].Value;

                                    if (scriptNode.Attributes["type"] != null)
                                        typ = scriptNode.Attributes["type"].Value;

                                    if (scriptNode.Attributes["language"] != null)
                                        lang = scriptNode.Attributes["language"].Value;
                                    if (scriptNode.InnerHtml != null)
                                        code = scriptNode.InnerHtml;

                                    func_name = ctrl + "_" + evt;
                                    if (ctrl != "window")
                                        new_script = Environment.NewLine + "function " + RemoveBrackets(func_name) + "(el)" + Environment.NewLine;
                                    else
                                        new_script = Environment.NewLine + "function " + AddBrackets(RemoveBrackets(func_name)) + Environment.NewLine;
                                    new_script += "{" + Environment.NewLine;


                new_script += "\r\n" + ReplaceThis(sFile, ctrl, evt, code, "this", "el") + "\r\n" + "}" + "\r\n";


                                    //remove for and event attributes
                                    scriptNode.Attributes["for"].Remove();
                                    scriptNode.Attributes["event"].Remove();

                                    //remove depraciated "language" attribute 
                                    //and replace it with "type" attribute
                                    if (scriptNode.Attributes["language"] != null)
                                        scriptNode.Attributes["language"].Remove();
                                    if (scriptNode.Attributes["type"] == null)
                                        scriptNode.Attributes.Add("type", "text/" + lang);

                                    //replace old javascript with a function code
                //HERE new_script variable contains the correct value but when I check  scriptNode.InnerHtml after assignment, it shows the messed up code.

                                    scriptNode.InnerHtml = new_script;
```

It is very strange and I can't seem to find a solution.

I have tried using HtmlEncode

scriptNode.InnerHtml = HtmlDocument.HtmlEncode(new_script);

And that produced the correct script, as specified above in second example, but replaced all the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` etc.

So the result was:

```
<script type="text/JScript">
function thisForm_onsubmit(el)
{

var Checked = false
var Counter = 0

for (;Counter &lt; el.choice.length; Counter++)
{
    if (el.choice[Counter].checked)
    {
        Checked = true
        el.action = el.choice[Counter].value
    }
}

if (!Checked)
{
    alert (&quot;Please make a selection&quot;)
    return false
}

}
</script>
```

I thought of using InnerText instead of InnerHtml, which makes more sense since what I am changing is not really HTML but InnerText property is read-only.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Are you working with multiple threads, and is there anything that is getting shared between those threads? It looks like what happens when multiple threads are both updating the same value - you get part of the output from one mingled with part of the output from the other.

Comment: No, no multiple threads

Comment: it is very strange as so far I have converted javascript for many files without an issue and just this particular one gives me a problem

Answer (score 1):

The modified script contains special character `<` which I really suspect caused the problem. `<` can easily misinterpreted as first character of an opening HTML tag, especially when it is used via `InnerHtml` property.

Here is one possible workaround. Assume that `new_script` is a string variable containing the modified Javascript, including the opening and closing tags (`<script type="text/JScript"></script>`). You can try to load `new_script` into a new `HtmlDocument`. Then replace the old script in the 1st 
`HtmlDocument` with the new script from the 2nd `HtmlDocument` instance :

```
.....
var newDoc = new HtmlDocument();
newDoc.LoadHtml(new_script);
var newScript = newDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script");
scriptNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newScript, script);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zK9A8O)</kbd>**

Comment: How can I create a new node? var newScript = newDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script"); just grabs the first <script> node but does not set any properties or javascript code